# cakephp SQL HELP! where?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to perform an SQL update in CakePHP. Here is my code:

```php
$sql = "
  UPDATE carts 
  SET
    qty = ".$this->data['Cart']['qty'].",
    process = 'UnPaid'
  WHERE ct_session_id = '".$this->data['Cart']['ct_session_id']."'
    AND product_id = '".$this->passedArgs['pd_id']."'
    AND key = '".$this->Session->read('Cart.key', $newCartkey)."'
";      
$this->Cart->query($sql);
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key = 'bwfgkxms'' at line 3
```

The query my code produces is:

```sql
UPDATE carts
SET
  qty = 111,
  process = 'UnPaid'
WHERE ct_session_id = '3254430f577669bb8ecdb8b8aadf1b96'
  AND product_id = '51'
  AND key = 'bwfgkxms'
```

Comment: Using CakePHP, but ignoring all conventions = probably not a good idea.  (Use CakePHP's save() functionality - it will save you from headaches like this)

Answer (score 8):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, you need to surround it with backticks in the column name.

```
$sql = "
 UPDATE carts 
 SET qty = ".$this->data['Cart']['qty'].", process = 'UnPaid'
 WHERE ct_session_id = '".$this->data['Cart']['ct_session_id']."'
   AND product_id = '".$this->passedArgs['pd_id']."'
   AND `key` = '".$this->Session->read('Cart.key', $newCartkey)."'
";
```

Comment: It's a collaborative effort :-D - Might be worth mentioning Bobby Tables as well, looks suspiciously like unescaped user input to me...

Answer (score 0):

It would greatly benefit you to get in the habit of using the CakePHP conventions.  There are many benefits to doing so, and when you do things like hand-write a query that could easily be done with CakePHP, you're making it more difficult on yourself as well as opening yourself up for many issues / security concerns in the future.

**The CakePHP way (with all the benefits included in following conventions):**

```
$this->Cart->updateAll(
    array(
        'Cart.qty' => $this->data['Cart']['qty'],
        'Cart.process' => 'UnPaid'),
    array(
       'Cart.ct_session_id' => $this->data['Cart']['ct_session_id'],
       'Cart.product_id' => $this->passedArgs['pd_id'],
       'Cart.key' => $this->Session->read('Cart.key', $newCartkey)
    )
);
```

More details on updating your data (and/or saving your data in general):
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions